# Why does "cmd /k" reset/clear/delete command history?

Tags: batch-file, reset, command-history

Can anyone explain why `cmd /k` clears the command history of my window terminal (`CMD`).
When I run a batch file within a previously `CMD` and I put `cmd /k` at the end of the line, the command history will be empty after running it.

If I remove `cmd /k` from the script I can go through the command history as usual.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by specifying `cmd` as a command, it actually launches a "cmd" within a "cmd".. which has its own process and therefore its own buffer and command history:

Hopefully this quick-n-dirty illustration I've put together will help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Fazer87 said, the new cmd session launched by `CMD /K` has its own command history. I suppose the designers of CMD.EXE could have opted to make a copy of the parent history, but they chose not to.

When you use EXIT to return to the parent cmd session, you will get back the original command history.

Comment: And, moreover, if you will launch a further _cmd_ session by `CMD /K` again (next to return to the parent _cmd_ session), then you will get back a `doskey /history` from the *prime* child _cmd_ session... Repeatable:)

Comment: @JosefZ - Whoa! That is totally unexpected and shocking behavior that I am able to confirm. Thanks for the info. The same behavior works for a WMIC session. Launch WMIC, issue some commands, EXIT, then launch a new WMIC session and the old session history is available. But if I then relaunch a new CMD session, then I get that old history. So a separate history is maintained for each flavor of child exe session. Very interesting.