# Cannot clear history of cmder / conemu

Tags: command-line, bash, cmd.exe, conemu, cmder

On Windows 10, I want to clear the entire history of the cmder /conemu command and bash window commands. However, I cannot delete even if I use the following approaches:

- Open .history file in `%CMDER_ROOT%\config\.history` and delete its content --> Not make any sense
- Run some commands e.g. `Alt+F7`, `history -c`

I am getting crazy when I see several commands that I used for Docker 2-3 months ago. I think there must be a way to clear the entire history or some of the history e.g. deleting some lines of the `.history` file. How can I perform this?

Comment: Deleting `C:\Program Files (x86)\cmder\config\.history` did it for me. Cmder must be closed when deleting.

Comment: I tried it and now I also tried again by closing cmder as you said. But does not make any sense and I see the entire history by using up and down arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

Some commands that should do it are:

- Delete the `C:\Program Files (x86)\cmder\config\.history` file.
- Enter the command `cmd /k` in the prompt (for some info on why it does this, see [Why does cmd/k reset/clear command history](https://superuser.com/questions/864081/why-does-cmd-k-reset-clear-delete-command-history)).
- Enter `doskey /listsize=0` in the prompt.

Comment: None of them is working :(

Comment: @ClintEastwood Really?  Dang it.  They all work okay for me.  Is there something else going on?

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot retrieve any command by using up/down keys after restarting cmder?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Yes.

Comment: I know it is weird, but I tried all of these methods and restarted the PC. Then try, but unfortunately again see the same list of commands.

Comment: By the way thanks a lot for your help and voted up.

Comment: try something simpler like  `history -c`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a specific entry or the entire file (clink_history), now at `...\Cmder\config`.

I installed Cmder using Chocolatey.org so I have it at `C:\tools\Cmder\config\`

Answer (score 0):

For ConEmu with clink you may find the history files in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\clink` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\clink`